# How to make multi-language static website in cakephp 3.2?

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

Need the steps to make the multi-language website in CakePHP 3.2.
The Content of website is static

Comment: That part is well documented on CakePHP cookbook

Comment: I need to know about only static content not all types of content without using translator . It is not documented.

Comment: This part is realy what you need https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Comment: I know where the cookbook is i need to know how to implement the translation

Answer (score 2):

Completed the code

language is changed in website using links for hindi and english any other language can also be added

```
<div class="navbar-brand pull-right" style='padding: 15px 0px;'>
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown">

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li>
                <?php 

                echo $this->Html->link("Hindi", array("controller" => "App", "action" => "changeLanguage",'hi')); 
                ?>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>

             <li>
                <?php 

                echo $this->Html->link("English", array("controller" => "App", "action" => "changeLanguage",'en')); 
                ?>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

in App Controller in initialize method following code is added

```
 $language = $this->Cookie->read('website_language');
    if (isset($language)) {
        I18n::locale($language);
    } else {
        I18n::locale('en_US');
    }
```

A new method is added for change

```
  public function changeLanguage($lang) {

    if (!empty($lang)) {
        if ($lang == 'hi') {
            //$this->request->session()->write('website_language', 'hi_IN');
            $this->Cookie->write('website_language', 'hi_IN');
        } else if ($lang == 'en') {
            //$this->request->session()->write('website_language', 'en_US');
            $this->Cookie->write('website_language', 'en_US');
        }
        //in order to redirect the user to the page from which it was called
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

Folders and files are created

```
/src
/Locale
    /en_US
        default.po
    /hi_IN
        default.po

  default.po
```

Hope it will be helpful.
If people don't know the answer to the question then don't down the question atleast :)

Comment: Your question isn't being downvoted because people don't know the answer, it's being downvoted beacuse it is poorly researched, lacks any details or even a problem description, and bascially asks for a step-by-step tutorial, which is considered offtopic here on StackOverflow. Please refer to the asking guide for more information on [**asking good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's very appreciated that you did some research and answered the question yourself, but it doesn't make the actual question any better, hence you'll probably receive further downvotes.

Comment: If i have to read a document to write a question on stackoverflow then i think it is better to search on google rather than writing question here....

Comment: Well, that's up to you to decide. If you just want answers fast, and don't want to put much effort in asking, then StackOverflow is probably not the right place for you, as this is a community that should be useful for everyone, and not just for particular individuals. If you learn how to properly formulate problems, then you'll not only receive better answers, but you'll also help future readers, and over time you'll get better at helping yourself, and you may become a part of the community that can help other questioners, and contribute to making StackOverflow a better place for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To Extend the answer of *Vinit*, In App Controller you need to setup **Cookie Component**.

```
use Cake\Controller\Component\CookieComponent;
```

Also initialize the component inside the Class

```
public $components = array('Cookie');
```